# Routes with question marks in routing table

Tags: ip, routing

When I do

```
ip route show table all
```

I see some routes with question marks in them as below.

```
multicast ???/32 from ???/32 table default proto none iif eth0
```

They appear to be multicast routes. I don't have any idea how they end up having these funny question marks. Actually I was even wondering if multicast routes shall be added to the routing table at all.

Anyone who could put some light on it?